# How update Widget when time is 23:59:59?

Tags: flutter, dart

After doing an event..I want to show up my `Text` widget and change that widget when the time is at 23:59:59... so far I have done this code

```
DateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(DateTime.now()) =="23:59:59"
                          ? Text("After")
                          : Text("Before")
```

but the problem is... whenever I close my app and then re-open app... the widget doesn't change from `Text("Before")` to `Text("After")` although the time is already at 23:59:59... the widget only change after I am doing an event click and when app is still opened... is there a way to solve that problem without any additional event?

Comment: So what are you expecting to see if you open the app at 00:00:00, before or after ?

Comment: I expect "after"

Comment: How you are sure that the exact second is similar, when you open the app ? If you want to show that text at 11:59 remove the second from the check ?

Comment: I am not really sure.. I just expect .. is there a way to show another widget after 23:59:59

Comment: You should revise the issue, because you said that `show another widget after 23:59:59`, but the code is to show **at** `23:59:59`. Moreover, everyday has `23:59:59`, so there is wired to say you want a widget before or after `23:59:59`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `Text`s in `build` method. This method works only on widget's update, for example, if state changes (that's why widget updates when you `do an event click`, I think your widget rebuilds after click). But widget doesn't know anything about `DateTime.now()`. So you should put `DateTime.now` to state and update it once in second.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: BeforeAfter(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BeforeAfter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BeforeAfterState createState() => _BeforeAfterState();
}

class _BeforeAfterState extends State<BeforeAfter> {
  String time = DateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(DateTime.now()); // our time which we will update

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    updateTime();
  }

  void updateTime() {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      updateTime();
      setState(() {
        time = DateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(DateTime.now()); // update time
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
       time == "12:13:00" ? Text("After") : Text("Before"), 
       Text(time)
    ]); // compare time with some value
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

---

Gif how it works

[image]

Comment: It works after I put ```DateTime.now``` to state and re install the app.. thank you very much for your help :DD